# ¿Cómo realizo el conteo de varios campos iguales? - count()

Tags: mysql, sql

Debo hacer la siguiente consulta:

- Verificar cuales son las facturas que han estado en más de un cargue.

Tengo este código:

```
select cartrn Transaccion, cardoc Factura, count(*) from cargued
where cartrn = '001' and cardoc = '00000064'
```

Resultado:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+
| Transaccion | Factura  | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+----------+
| 001         | 00000064 |        2 |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Ahora le cambiaré el número de factura:

```
select cartrn Transaccion, cardoc Factura, count(*) from cargued
where cartrn = '001' and cardoc = '00000004'
```

Resultado:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+
| Transaccion | Factura  | count(*) |
+-------------+----------+----------+
| 001         | 00000004 |        3 |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

En pocas palabras, mi `from` es de los *cargue*, lo que debo hacer es que hay más de una factura repetida, pero con diferente transacción:

```
001 - Factura de venta
002 - Devolución
```

El requerimiento me pide sólo las facturas, osea solo las '001', por eso en la siguiente consulta, si lo hacemos sin la condición del `where` para cartrn veremos 4, de las cuales sólo son 3. esa factura ha estado en más de un cargue.

```
mysql> select cartrn Transacion, cardoc Factura from cargued
    -> where cardoc = '00000004';
+------------+----------+
| Transacion | Factura  |
+------------+----------+
| 001        | 00000004 |
| 002        | 00000004 |
| 001        | 00000004 |
| 001        | 00000004 |
+------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Esto es lo que se espera al final de la consulta, pero no logro hacerlo.

[image: Consulta final]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto parece ser un simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT cartrn Transaccion, cardoc Factura, count(*) NumeroCargues
FROM cargued
WHERE cartrn = '001'
GROUP BY cartrn, cardoc
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY cartrn, cardoc;
```

Comment: Si el op indica que necesita las facturas que tengan mas de un cargue, sería conveniente agregar una cláusula having count(*) > 1

Comment: Exactamente, justo lo que edité al final del código.

Comment: @JYass no había leído esa parte de la pregunta. Toda la razón, ya agregué la condición

Comment: @Lamak sin embargo, tengo una consulta sobre el group by. ¿Este que hace por lo menos en este caso?. Por que cuando no hago ese group by me suma todo en una sola línea de la consulta.

Comment: @AndrésJValencia Lo que pasa es que explicar la funcionalidad de un `GROUP BY` es algo que es más apto para un tutorial, no entra de la temática de preguntas-respuestas de SO.

Comment: @Lamak comprendo de todas formas muchas gracias por la colaboración de ambos.